# Github Workflow edit 1 file when new branch is made?

Tags: github, github-actions, workflow

I've been trying to write a GitHub workflow, but it has been pretty confusing. All I want to do is to have a workflow that'll write to a file, called `changes.md`. Whenever you create a new branch, the workflow will edit the `changes.md` file and put the name of it and the day and time it was made. For example:

```
# Changes
- This branch is titled Test Branch
- This branch was made by Bugs Bunny
- This branch was made on January 1, 1970 <!--Or 1/1/1970--> @ 12:00:00 AM
```

I also want there to be a `changes.txt` file, which you just list what you did. Like:

```
Added foo
Fixed bar glitch
```

Then the workflow automatically appends the changes to the bottom of the `changes.md` file

Is this even possible?

Comment: Remember that GitHub actions operate in a working tree that is based on a *copy* of some repository. You don't have the original repository at hand.

Comment: The only way for me to do it is to create a bot on some other program then?

Comment: It's fine to write files and build a program from the files you wrote and put that on an artifact server. It's less fine (more problematic) to clone a repository, manipulate the repository, add new commits, and push the new commits somewhere—but it *is* possible to do that, you just have to remember that you need to set up your GitHub action to do all of that. I'm no github-actions-guru but there's a lot of GitHub documentation here.